# Unable to use J2ssh library in GWT application server code to make SSH connection

Tags: java, gwt, ssh

I am writing a GWT application and in that I am trying to make SSH connection to a server using private key. For this I am using J2SSH library. But, while executing this, I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I make SSH connection to a remote server from GWT application server package? Please advice.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are getting an Access Control issue with the application environment.

[Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_Troubleshooting.html#AccessControlException_access_denied) it is stated that

> The problem occurs if you mistakenly enabled the Google App Engine feature for your project when you created the project, or at a later time during development, and have server-side libraries or classes packaged with your GWT application war folder that violate the Java App Engine sandbox."

You may also want to consider upgrading the [J2SSH library](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick), if you want a similar interface to J2SSH use the more recent J2SSH Maverick release from the same author (that is me btw).

This version of the API does not try to set any thread properties and therefore if you do need to run this in the Google App Engine you will have more success.